# Как удалить строку из массива Numpy по заданному условию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Например имеется массив:

```
[[ 0  2.2657  1]
[ 1  6.0596  1]
[ 2  1.3483  1]
[ 9 -1.2633 -1]
[ 9 -1.3023 -1]
[ 1 -1.3930  1]]
```

Необходимо найти все номера строк, где в третьем столбце есть -1 и удалить их, чтобы на выходе получилось следующее:

```
[[ 0  2.2657  1]
[ 1  6.0596  1]
[ 2  1.3483  1]
[ 1 -1.3930  1]]
```

Я пытался это сделать это так:

```
# Преобразуем данные в матрицу из трёх столбцов
data_read = np.genfromtxt('test.csv') 
# Выделяем третий столбец
voltage = data_read[:,2]
voltage = voltage[:, np.newaxis] 
# По условию находим все индексы, где значение столбца = -1
index = np.where(voltage == -1) 
# Удаляем все строки с определёнными индексами 
data_read = np.delete(data_read, index , axis=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([
    [0, 2.2657, 1],
    [1, 6.0596, 1],
    [2, 1.3483, 1],
    [9, -1.2633, -1],
    [9,-1.3023, -1],
    [1, -1.3930, 1],
])

res = array[array[:, 2] != -1]

print(res)
```